# How do I write non-ascii characters to a text file using a Python program?

Tags: python-3.x, text-files, non-ascii-characters

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
dictionary = {'à': 'a grave', 'â': 'a circumflex', 'ç': 'c cedille', 'é': 'e aigu', 'è': 'e grave', 'ê': 'e circumflex', 'ï': 'i umlet', 'î': 'i cedille', 'ô': 'o circumflex', 'ù': 'u grave', 'û': 'u circumflex'}

location = 'C://Users//Nelson//Desktop//Python//0_Projects//0_Personal//MasterFrenchDictionary//'
#name = raw_input('File Name: ')
name = 'test'

dict_str = str(dictionary)
dict_str = dict_str.replace('{', '')
dict_str = dict_str.replace('}', '')
dict_str = dict_str.replace(', ', '\n')
dict_str = dict_str.replace('l\'', '*')
dict_str = dict_str.replace('d\'', '*')
dict_str = dict_str.replace('"', "'")
dict_str = dict_str.replace("'", '')
dict_str = dict_str.replace('*', "l'")

file = open(location + name + '.txt', 'w')
file.write(dict_str)
file.close()
```

This is the code I am using to help me debug a program I am building. The program has access to a text file that contains every French word I have learned so far in my French class, and it's definition. In this mini-debugging program I have, the dictionary will be taken as a string, then the syntax characters are removed. Line one in the text file is a word: it's definition, line two is a word: it's definition... you get the idea. In French, there are various accented characters that are not recognized by ascii as I am sure you are aware. When the program writes these characters, I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuEpm.png) (the accented character: the letter and the accent name).

I tried using the codecs module to fix the problem:
I replaced the code:

```
file = open(location + name + '.txt', 'w')
file.write(dict_str)
file.close()
```

with:

```
with codecs.open(location + name + '.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as out:  
    out.write(u'%s' % dict_str)
```

but this created [new problems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWeSV.png).

**How do I write non-ascii characters to a text file using a Python program?**

Any help is much appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you tried passing `encoding='utf-8'` as a keyword argument to your `open` call?

Comment: Your file looks like it contains the characters you wanted, encoded as utf-8. Open the file in a text editor that supports utf-8 and see what it looks like.

Answer (score 0):

### Editor problem

Running your code with Python 3.4, I get this file content:

```
ê: e circumflex
à: a grave
ç: c cedille
è: e grave
é: e aigu
û: u circumflex
ï: i umlet
â: a circumflex
ù: u grave
î: i cedille
ô: o circumflex
```

What editor do you use to open the result file? If on Windows, use [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/). If it still shows something strange, try changing the encoding in the editor manually.

### Improved solution

This should produce the same results without all the replacing:

```
with open('unicode_out.txt', 'w') as fobj:
    for k, v in dictionary.items():
        fobj.write('{}: {}\n'.format(k, v))
```

Comment: I am currently using Enthought Canopy. I have installed Notepad++ but I have yet to use it. Thank you for the improved solution. I do not have python installed because Canopy takes care of that, but I will download it and try using notepad. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Nelson It should only take a second or two. Just open Notepad++ and go to menu `File-->Open` and open the file you generated.